# Вывести значение массива

Tags: php, массивы

Не могу вывести значение 'name'.
использую twig и [TMDB-PHP-API](http://code.octal.es/php/tmdb-api/index.html)

```
var_dump($movie->getGenres()):

array (size=3)
  0 => 
    object(Genre)[37]
      private '_data' => 
        array (size=2)
          'id' => int 28
          'name' => string 'Р±РѕРµРІРёРє' (length=12)
  1 => 
    object(Genre)[38]
      private '_data' => 
        array (size=2)
          'id' => int 12
          'name' => string 'РїСЂРёРєР»СЋС‡РµРЅРёСЏ' (length=22)
  2 => 
    object(Genre)[39]
      private '_data' => 
        array (size=2)
          'id' => int 14
          'name' => string 'С„СЌРЅС‚РµР·Рё' (length=14)
```

В основном ошибка "Array to string conversion in ... : eval()'d"

Comment: А как пытались вывести?

Comment: Есть подозрение что это обертка в каком-то фреймворке, например symfony

Comment: @soux приведите пример того как получаете это.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте это обрабатывать циклично и обращаться `$row['name']` или `$row->name`. Думаю что-то из этого поможет.

Comment: Не помогло, выводит ошибку аля: не найдено 'name'

Comment: @soux попробуйте $row->getName();